# Funcion AJAX en laravel no retorna los datos del controlador

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel

Buenas, estoy haciendo un buscador a tiempo real en laravel con AJAX jquery, pero los datos del controlador no se retornan a success. Aqui les dejo el ejemplo...

```js
$('#searchReports').on('keyup', function(){

     var data = $('#searchReports').val();

         var request =
         $.ajax({
             url:"127.0.0.1:8000/buscar",
             data: data,
             dataType: 'json',
             method: 'GET',
         })
         request.done(function(response)
         {
             $('tbody').text(response);
         })
         request.fail(function(jqXHR, textstatus)
         {
             console.log("Hubo un error" + textstatus);
        })
})
```

el controlador:

```
public function select(Request $request)
{

    $data = $request->input('searcher');

    $query = Reporte::select('*')->where('instituto','like' ,'%'.$data.'%')
                    ->orWhere('representante','like' ,'%'.$data.'%')
                    ->orWhere('asunto','like' ,'%'.$data.'%')
                    ->orWhere('estado','like' ,'%'.$data.'%')->get();

    $total = $query->count();

    if ($total > 0) {

        foreach ($query as $row) {
            $response = "
            <tr>
                <td>".$row->instituto."</td>
                <td>".$row->representante."</td>
                <td>".$row->asunto."</td>
                <td>".$row->estado."</td>
            </tr>
        ";
        }
    }
    echo $response;

}
```

Cuando empiezo a escribir en el buscador lo unico que me aparece en consola es : "hubo un error" , lo que envia el codigo ajax desde "request.fail()"...

¿Alguna solución?.

Comment: ¿Qué código HTTP está siendo entregado? Por cierto, no debería ser responsabilidad del controlador dibujar la tabla. Se ven varios errores potenciales en el código.

Comment: Seguro que la ruta es /buscar?

Comment: -Shaz, no, no le he agregado codigo http, pero he visto ejemplos de jquery ajax que sirven sin eso.. por eso lo hice así.

Comment: -Igmer, Si la ruta es buscar, ya lo comprobé con una etiqueta "a href" con la ruta buscar, y me envia sin problemas

Comment: @Abdiel creo que no entendiste mi pregunta. TODA solicitud HTTP entrega un código (al menos en la gran mayoría de casos como este), es como si me dijeras que tú no tienes un nombre.

Comment: Mmm, bueno sinceramente no se de eso, pudieras decirme como te ubico el codigo http o como lo genero?

Comment: Segun entiendo en tu archivo web de rutas, deberia tener asignado un nombre para ajax y si es buscar solo pon `/buscar`

Comment: Como te dice un compañero anteriormente, checa el código de error en consola (404, 403, 419, 500...). Y en tu consulta podrías ponerla en un try{//consulta+codigo}catch(\Exception $exception){                return response()->json([
                    'code'=>'500',
                    'status'=>'error',
                    'details' => $exception
                    ], 500);} para que sepas si ahí está un error

Answer (score 0):

Me parece que es porque no estas agregando el CSRF-TOKEN en el header, prueba lo siguiente

```
    $.ajax({
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        }, 
        url: "127.0.0.1:8000/buscar",
        data: data,
        dataType: 'json',
        method: 'GET',
    })
    request.done(function (response) {
        $('tbody').text(response);
    })
    request.fail(function (jqXHR, textstatus) {
        console.log("Hubo un error" + textstatus);
    })
```

Lo anterior suponiendo que tienes la etiqueta `<meta name='csrf-token' content='xxxx'>` si no, tendrás que buscar la manera de obtener ese token